# Why does "for I := 0to aList.Count-1 do" work with a missing space?

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors

I was writing a small console application in Delphi (XE), and by mistake wrote:

```
for I := 0to aList.Count-1 do
```

Note the missing space between "0" and "to"

I didn't notice this until after I had run the program, and I was surprised the compiler accepted this. It's probably no big deal, but it made me curious.

Why does Delphi accept this typo?

Comment: Just a guess but AFAIK, compilers are implemented as state machines. I can imagine the compiler encountering a `for` loop entering a *read numbers up until first non-digit character* state.

Comment: While the compiler will build this code, certain other things, like Pascal Analyzer (from peganza) will stop hard and fail to parse units like this. I know because I ran into exactly that `0to` without a space, and it choked on that. i wouldn't be surprised if the code-completion/error-insight parsers, and the delphi IDE code-formatter barfed on this too, and so it might break lots of things, while the code still builds.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's for the same reason that you don't need spaces around the `.` or the `-`. Since a `t` can never come after an initial `0` in any recognisable token, the lexical analyser simply returns the `0` as an integer-literal token, and then recognises the `to` as a distinct keyword token. If you had made a different mistake instead — `for I := 0 to10` — you'd now have a problem, since `to10` is recognised as a valid identifier, which is illegal immediately after the `0`.

Comment: Good explanation, it makes sense now.

Comment: As a consequence of this explanation, `if condition then i := 7else i := 42;` won't work without the space after `7`, because the tokenizer would try to build a floating point number from `7e` and will yield an error because the character `l` is illegal in a floating point literal.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: An excellent point! I briefly wondered what other scenarios would lead to interesting surprises, but couldn't think of any, off the cuff.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: As a particular example confirming your words, Borland Pascal 7 compiler stumbles over that line complaining about type mismatch if `i` is an `Integer` and expecting a `;` after `7e` if `i` is a `Real`. Also, if `i` is a `Real`, the following is compiled successfully: `if condition then i := 7eelse i := 42;` (note the two successive `e`s).

Answer (score 14):

If we exclude the line comment for simplicity, then we'll find that your piece of code contains these 11 tokens:

- `for`
- `I`
- `:=`
- `0`
- `to`
- `aList`
- `.`
- `Count`
- `-`
- `1`
- `do`

In order for the compiler to recognise them, they must be represented unambiguously. That is, if any two neighbouring tokens, when put next to each other, create an ambiguity as to their meaning, then a *delimiter* (`space`, `tab`, `carriage return`, `line feed`) is required between them.

Now, if you take any such pair of tokens, you'll see two places where delimiters are really *required*: one is between `for` and `I` (`forI` vs `for I`) and the other is between `to` and `aList` (`toaList` vs `to aList`). As for delimiting `0` and `to`, in particular (and, similarly, `1` and `do`), they do not create any ambiguity *to the compiler*. `0` is a numeral, `t` is not, so `t` cannot possibly form a single token with `0` in any sensible (to the compiler) way. That is, as soon as the compiler encounters `t`, it immediately recognises it as the beginning of another token, without there having to be a delimiter between the two.

We do usually put a space between numbers and subsequent 'words' (identifiers or keywords), because that improves readability of our code, but that's all there is to it.